# python fabric: prevent already installed packages from being installed again

Tags: python-2.7, fabric

So writing a fabfile function, I attempt to automate the setup of a particular mac os x machine like this.

```
from fabric.api import local, env, sudo, require

def mac_port_setup():
    PACKAGES = ['vim +python27', 'htop']
    for item in PACKAGES:
        local('sudo port -v install {0}'.format(item))
```

The `PACKAGES` list can actually be a huge list and I want to avoid installing a package if the package is already installed. What are the possible ways to go about preventing an already installed package from being re-installed in my fabric automation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure running the install again won't do anything on already installed packages. If you want to check first port has the installed command to list what's been installed.